# How to pass variables from while loop of PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm creating one Graph chart using Google APIs I used Java Script source from Google. In PHP I'm using while loop where I fetch some array row using query, this mysql query works fine, and values of fetched array are also correct (When I echoed that in PHP) but problem is that how do I pass this values to JavaScripts function?
My PHP code is as follows :

```
while ($graph_result = mysqli_fetch_row($graph)) 
{
    $graphCount = $graph_result[0];
    $graphMonth = $graph_result[1];
    echo $graphCount; // This works
    echo $graphMonth;
}
```

This gives me in result of two rows, each contains two values listed below:

[image]

Now I want to pass this above values to Java script function so that it draws Graph chart for me, my javascript code is as follows:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'users'],
        [graphMonth, graphCount]  // Here I have to place PHP values !
    ]); 
}
```

So how to pass this values to JS ???

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

In PHP

```
$i = 0;
while ($graph_result = mysqli_fetch_row($graph)) 
{
    $graph_values[$i]["count"] = $graph_result[0];
    $graph_values[$i]["month"] = $graph_result[1];
    $i++;
}
```

In script,

```
<script>
    <?php foreach($graph_values as $key){ ?>
    drawChart('<?php echo $key["count"]; ?>', '<?php echo $key["month"]; ?>');
    <?php } ?>

function drawChart(graphCount, graphMonth) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'users'],
        [graphMonth, graphCount] 
    ]); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php while ($graph_result = mysqli_fetch_row($graph)) 
{
   ?>
<script>
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'users'],
        [<?php echo $graph_result[0]; ?>, <?php echo $graph_result[1]; ?>]
    ]); 
}
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I don't know if it is best practice or not..

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to do that.
In your while loop, build an associative array and encode it in json:

```
$jsonArray = array();
while ($graph_result = mysqli_fetch_row($graph)) 
{
    $graphCount = $graph_result[0];
    $graphMonth = $graph_result[1];
    $jsonArray[] = array($graphCount, $graphMonth);
}
echo '<div id="json">' . json_encode($jsonArray) . '</div>';
```

And then recover it in your javascript:

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').innerHTML);
function drawChart(json_data) {
    var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number','Months');
    data.addColumn('number','users');
    data.addRows(json_data);
}
```